# A column with average loss per day only in last row -pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
|Day      |water level  | Avg loss per day |
|---------|-------------|------------------|
|1        |  200        | NaN              |
|2        |  190        | NaN              |
|3        |  180        | NaN              |
|4        |  175        | NaN              |
|5        |  174        | NaN              |
|6        |  172        | NaN              |
|7        |  170        | (200-170)/7      |
```

I need the data in the Avg loss per day column to be like above .
I tried using iloc and np.nan but i was getting error saying the
single indexer out of bounds. i used this

```
                df['Avg loss per day']=(df['water level'].iloc[0]-df['water level'].iloc[6])/7
                df = df.round({'Avg loss per day': 2})
                df.loc[0:6,['Avg loss per day']]=np.nan
```

Is there any other method of doing this without using iloc or np.nan

Comment: Do you have a larger df than this? What if you df has 14 days instead of only 7? For you example, it really is simpler to just using loc and assign.

Comment: `df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Avg loss per day')] = ((df['water level'].iloc[0] - df['water level'].iloc[-1])/len(df)).round(2)`